# Get font of recognized character with Tesseract-OCR

Tags: tesseract

Is it possible to get the font of the recognized characters with Tesseract-OCR, i.e. are they Arial or Times New Roman, either from the command-line or using the API.

I'm scanning documents that might have different parts with different fonts, and it would be useful to have this information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tesseract has an API `WordFontAttributes` function defined in [`ResultIterator`](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/blob/3.04/ccmain/ltrresultiterator.cpp) class that you can use.

Comment: As of a recent Tesseract version, `WordFontAttributes` seems to return `None` no matter what. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1074

Comment: Yes, I can see why because it is using a neural network now. Any more of the updates is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Based on [nguyenq's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/754060/nguyenq) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15693969/4743961) i wrote a simple python script that prints the font name for each detected char. This script uses the python lib [tesserocr](https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr).

```py
from tesserocr import PyTessBaseAPI, RIL, iterate_level

def get_font(image_path):
    with PyTessBaseAPI() as api:
        api.SetImageFile(image_path)
        api.Recognize()
        ri = api.GetIterator()
        level = RIL.SYMBOL
    
        for r in iterate_level(ri, level):
            symbol = r.GetUTF8Text(level)
            word_attributes = r.WordFontAttributes()

            if symbol:
                 print(u'symbol {}, font: {}'.format(symbol, word_attributes['font_name']))

  get_font('logo.jpg')
```

Comment: What config & version of tesseract, tessdata and other dependencies used? I am getting word_attributes as None

Comment: I also have word_Attributes as None if anyone has figured this out?

Comment: On the link above it says "The LSTM engine does not support font attributes other than point size, and as I said 4 years ago, it won't support these attributes any time soon (It is not planned).

However, the legacy engine is still available in versions 4.x and 5.x and it supports these attributes. You need a model that includes data for the legacy engine and you need to use --oem 0 (It might also work with --oem 3, not sure)."