# OCR Tesseract - Get Image Font Attributes

Tags: python, image, image-processing, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have been using `Pytesseract` to extract text from image. I am currently in a restoration task of an image document. Aside from extracting text from an image, I also wanted to identify each words `font`, `font size`, whether the `character is capital or not`, `italicized or not`, `bold or not` and so and so forth. Is this currently possible with Tesseract? I have read the documentation of [Pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/), but found none about it. If this is not possible, how can I make it happen? Is there any open source font recognition API's? Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution for font size, yet?

Comment: see the anwser here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679017/get-font-of-recognized-character-with-tesseract-ocr