# Delphi tesseract wrapper does not recognize font names

Tags: delphi, ocr, tesseract

I'm using Delphi Tesseract wrapper which is available at https://github.com/CloudDelphi/TTesseractOCR4. Based on example here: [Get font of recognized character with Tesseract-OCR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15679017/get-font-of-recognized-character-with-tesseract-ocr) I should call `api.GetIterator()` method to get `WordFontAttributes()`. As I see Delphi wrapper does not support `api.GetIterator()` directly but has `TTesseractPageLayout.AnalyseLayout` function to access `GetIterator()`.

In `OnRecognizeEnd` I call `AnalyseLayout`, which returns words' texts but not font names:

```
 Tesseract.PageLayout.AnalyseLayout;
  for TesseractWord in Tesseract.PageLayout.Words do
  begin
     memo1.Lines.Add(TesseractWord.Text);
     memo1.Lines.Add(TesseractWord.FontName);
  end;
```

Could you please help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: The newer LSTM engine which uses a neural network doesn't support it. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1074

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using tesseract version >= 4.0.0.0.
On those versions, the recognition is done with neural networks (LSTM engine), so the font name is not available. The latest version that you can get the font name, is version 3, which uses the old engine.

You can read about it in the following links (user summited issues on official github repo):

1. https://github.com/sirfz/tesserocr/issues/292
2. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/3820
3. https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1074